# in PHP, how do I check how long it has been since the user last used my Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, notifications, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the facebook notifications api and in the documentation there is a requirement that you only send notifications to users that have been logged in in the last 28 days. Will anyone point me to a php example that shows how to do this with the php SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store this information in your own databases.

Facebook does not have an API to tell you the last time a specific user used your app; the restriction you're referring to from the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications/) is a policy/best practice and not a technical limitation on the API as far as I know

If you don't know the last time someone used your app, you may be thinking about the Notifications API incorrectly, as it's intended for notifying existing users of something which has changed since their last visit to the app - if you don't know when that last visit was and what has changed since then, you probably shouldn't be sending them notifications

Comment: right. I'm only using notifications to alert users to when something relevant to their most recent usage has changed. Meaning they naturally wouldn't get a notification unless they have recently used the app. As long as it's just a best practice tip I'm fine. I thought it was something mandatory.